# No rule to make XXX error in GNU make

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm new to Makefile. While trying to write a generic Makefile which could be used in most of my projects with least modification, I encountered a problem (simplified as the following):

My "project" looks like:

```
proj/
    src1.cpp
    subdir1/
        src2.cpp
    Makefile
```

Part of the `Makefile`:

```
OBJ := bin/src1.o bin/subdir1/src2.o
OBJ_DIR := bin/ bin/subdir1/
PROGRAMS := prog1
define compile_template =
$(1)/%.o: %.cpp
    mkdir -p $$(@D)
    $$(CXX) $$(CXXFLAGS) -c $$< -o $$@
endef

define PROGRAM_template =
$(1): $$(OBJ)
    $$(CXX) $$(LDFLAGS) $$^ -o $$@ $$(LDLIBS)
endef

$(foreach odir,$(OBJ_DIR),$(eval $(call compile_template,$(odir))))
$(foreach prog,$(PROGRAMS),$(eval $(call PROGRAM_template,$(prog))))
```

And the error is:

```
gmake: *** No rule to make target `bin/src1.o', needed by `proj1'.  Stop.
```

Another question is should I wrote my own Makefile or use automake etc if I only compile in particular machines (So I have control to the compiler, OS, ...)?

Comment: This could be a silly answer, but did you use tab delimiter, isn't it? When I use makefile, this usually was my source of troubles (a long time ago). By the way, try to use cmake

Comment: @TomásBadan I did use tab. The cmake seems to be a good option, thank you for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to debug issues like this (problems with eval) is to replace the `$(eval ...)` function with a call to `$(info ...)`.  This will print out the text that make is parsing and it's usually pretty obvious what your problem is.  If you rewrite your eval lines to this:

```
$(foreach odir,$(OBJ_DIR),$(info $(call compile_template,$(odir))))
$(foreach prog,$(PROGRAMS),$(info $(call PROGRAM_template,$(prog))))
```

(and fixing your obvious syntax error, the space between `:` and `=` in the first line) you see:

```
bin//%.o: %.cpp
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
bin/subdir1//%.o: %.cpp
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
prog1: $(OBJ)
        $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)
```

From this you can see the `prog1` depends on `bin/src1.o` and `bin/subdir1/src2.o` so make wants to build `bin/src1.o`.  It looks through your rules, but in make's internal matching syntax `bin//%.o` does *not* match `bin/src1.o` because of the extra slash.

Change your assignment to remove the trailing slash and it should work better:

```
OBJ_DIR := bin bin/subdir1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know the function `info` before you mentioned. +1!